# Docker Desktop UI Port Links

Tags: docker, docker-desktop

I have containers & images set up in Docker Desktop.
The images have "clickable links" in the Port(s) column, but they are not exposed with the correct protocol. (See image - 443 should open as https but is always http)

What do I need to configure either in the yaml or Dockerfile so that the link is opened with the correct protocol (http or https) ?

[image: Incorrect protocol]

I've googled a lot, and maybe its that I'm new to all this (less than a week now), but I can't find a definitive guide to understand this.

There are so many options & commands in yaml and Dockerfile and I'm struggling to find the answer.